# Difference between date and date_gmt

Tags: comments, timezones

In my database `comment_date` and `comment_date_gmt` are different. `comment_date` is in UTC+3, but `comment_date_gmt` in UTC+0.

Why? What do I not right? When I leave the comment I can see "You left a comment 3 hours ago"

Answer (score 1):

The database is correct in this case. `comment_date` is the datetime of your WordPress timezone setting and `comment_date_gmt` is the same datetime, but converted to Greenwich Mean Time (GMT). [GMT is the timezone all other timezones are offset from while UTC is the time standard](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/gmt-utc-time.html). In most practical applications they're interchangeable.

The problem you're probably having is either saving or reading the datetime converted to your local timezone from either GMT or your site's set timezone.